# How can I use column to delimit on tabs and not spaces?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, quoting, columns

I'd like to use the Unix `column` command to format some text. I have fields delimited by tabs, but within each field there are also spaces. `column` delimits on white space (tabs and spaces). How can I make column only use tabs as the delimiter?

I was trying to specify tab as the delimiter using:

```
cat myfile | column -t -s"\t"
```

Answer (score 145):

```
column -t -s '\t'
```

would separate columns on `\` and `t` characters.

<strike>`column -s \t`</strike> is the same as `column -s 't'`, as the backslash is interpreted as a quoting operator by the shell.

Here you want to pass a real TAB character to column. With ksh93, zsh, bash, mksh, busybox sh or FreeBSD sh:

```
column -ts $'\t'
```

Or enter a real tab character by typing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the shell prompt (within quotes or preceded by a backslash as the tab character is a token separator in the shell syntax just like space), or use `"$(printf '\t')"` (those double quotes needed to disable the split+glob operator as the tab character also happens to be in the default value of `$IFS`).

Comment: I had to do `column -t -s $'\t'` as bash seemed to think `'\t'` mean both `\ ` and `t`, but `$'\t'` means a literal tab. Bash stinks

Comment: If you need POSIX compliancy (lord help me), please see my answer, which is heavily based on this fantastic answer!

Comment: This solution worked for me -- the `$'\t'` makes tab the delimiter.  But I'm pretty sure I do `awk -F "\t"` to use a tab as a delimiter for awk.  Why does that work and not here for column?

Comment: Can I suggest that your answer would be better if the top line were the solution with the explanation below it, rather than the top line being something that *doesn't* answer the question.

Comment: THANK you! Good gods, I must have been at this for 20 minutes now! I didn't know the `$'\t'` syntax... great tip!

Answer (score 20):

For POSIX, `$'...'`, as known as ANSI-C escaping, isn't defined.

Instead, you can use the [POSIX `$(printf '\t')`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

```
column -t -s "$(printf '\t')"
```

---

`$(printf '\011')` could be used, as `011` (octal representation of decimal 9) is the ANSI code for a horizontal tab character:

```
column -t -s "$(printf '\011')"
```

However this is discouraged as it was commented under this [and his answer by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57222/how-can-i-use-column-to-delimit-on-tabs-and-not-spaces#comment852990_57235). This is because it may not be consistent across shell versions as POSIX doesn't specify what the **encoding** of TAB is. There are still POSIX systems whose C locale encoding is EBCDIC based where TAB is 5, not 9 like in ASCII. Wherever possible, it's better to refer to characters by name (`\t` here) to avoid this kind of issue. Note that `$'...'` is planned for inclusion in the next major version of the POSIX specification as of Sep 10, 2018.

Comment: Note that POSIX doesn't specify what the encoding of TAB is. There are still POSIX systems whose C locale encoding is EBCDIC based where TAB is 5, not 9 like in ASCII. Wherever possible, it's better to refer to characters by name to avoid this kind of issue like with `"$(printf '\t')"` as shown in my answer. Note that `$'...'` is planned for inclusion in the next major version of the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 9):

I used the following (only works if your text does not contain `|`):

```
cat myfile | tr '\t' '|' | column -t -s '|'
```

This just replaces tabs with pipes, then uses column with pipes as delimiters.

(I did this because I didn't see anything in [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57235/318461) that worked out-of-the-box in the fish shell. Otherwise, [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57235/318461) seems good.)

Comment: excellent work-around!

Answer (score 2):

The `-t` is for selecting the number of columns you want. Leaving this blank does not change anything. Also, you want white space after the `-s` so try this out:

`cat myfile | column -s \t`

Comment: Thanks. This is close to what I am looking for. However, now all the lines are merged onto one line. How can I keep each line on its own line?

Comment: By default, `column` fills rows before columns. You may be interested in `pr`

Comment: This wasn't true for me when using `pactl list short sources | column -ts $'\t'`. It doesn't work as expected without the `t`.